# After Effects - Path with cut out

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to animate a logo to create a loader.  As part of this animation I want to convert the logo symbol to a 3d object and spin it.

I have created a shape layer and pasted a path from illustrator.  To note - the path was created using the pathfinder minus front option to create a hollow centre - and looks like this:

[image]

When pasting as a path After Effects initially  inverts the path as such:
[image]

if i then click invert alongside mask :

[image]

it displays correctly.  But if I then change the shape layer to a 3d layer I loose the cut out -

[image]

can anyone please advise where i'm going wrong and what i can do to correct?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Any reason you're not importing the file from illustrator? Using the shape as a mask on a shape layer is a complicated way of doing things.

Comment: hi @stib I'm new to AE and was following a. tutorial - it mentioned that this method allowed depth extrusion